# Optimal packing of a tile without rotation or reflection

Tags: geometry, tiling, packing-problem

Let's say we have a shape.  We will call this shape $A$ and we will say that $A$ is some finite subset of the regular square tiling.  Similar to a polyomino, except we do not require that $A$ has a connected interior.

Now I would like to a the optimal way to pack copies of $A$ on the plane without rotation or reflection.  For example if $A$ were:

[image: Shape]

one optimal packing would be:

[image: Tiling]

another would be:

[image: Tiling 2]

despite the fact that if we were allowed to rotate or reflect $A$ we would be able to tile the plane perfectly.

I've been trying to come up with an algorithm to find an optimal packing for arbitrary $A$, but I am rather stumped and looking through literature I was not able to find any work on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The disconnected polyominoes you refer to are more commonly known as *animals* on the square lattice, though some authors frustratingly use this terminology to refer only to polyominoes. "Translational packing density" is the term I'd use for what you are looking for here, though I agree that it seems there is not much research in this direction.

The problem is likely fairly difficult, or at least not one for which provably correct algorithms are known. Not until [Bhattacharya 2016](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.05738.pdf) did we even have a provably correct algorithm for the decision problem of whether this density is equal to $1$ (i.e. whether the animal tiles the plane), and that only via the fact that such tilings must be periodic, which does not lend itself to nice runtime bounds - we just alternately check for periodic tilings of a certain size and try to exhaustively prove impossibility within a certain radius, until one of the two avenues succeeds.

The more general optimization problem in this question seems unlikely to have been solved. Of course it is hard to guarantee such things, but given the recency of more specialized results than this and my not having seen such results in a reasonably wide survey of polyomino-adjacent literature, I would be surprised to learn that any effective algorithms were known.

(Although empirically, it doesn't seem to be too hard to get optimal results quickly just by trying small periodic tilings - in the case of polyominoes, I verified a while ago that the optimal translational packing densities all result from *isohedral* arrangement of the polyominoes (i.e. with their centroids in a lattice) for every polyomino with at most $6$ cells.)

Comment: The algorithm provided actually can be pretty trivially used to get an algorithm for the more general problem, albeit an extremely slow one.  Simply check the initial animal if it's density is not 1, run the algorithm again on every way to extend the animal by one adjacent square.  If none succeed run with every way to extend by two etc.  Eventually some superset of the tile will tile with density 1, so this does halt and the tiling of the superset is the most dense possible tiling of the original animal.

Comment: This assumes that the maximum-density packing will be a tiling of a larger animal containing the chosen one - I don't see any reason why this would be true in all cases (in fact I would guess it is often false).

Comment: Ah, I realize I never mentioned in the question that I was only interested in periodic tilings anyway, which should force this condition.

Comment: I think even then it is not guaranteed, unless you want to enforce the stronger condition of being isohedral? I don't have an example offhand, but in the case of non-translational tilings, [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/3960112/) shows a maximum-density packing of a non-tiling heptomino $H$ which cannot be realized as a tiling of any polyomino containing $H$.