# What is the smallest polyomino that can't surround a $1\times 1$ hole?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, polyomino

Given a polyomino $P$, we can ask if it is possible for disjoint copies of $P$ to surround a single cell in the square grid - i.e., for the complement of their union to have a connected component of size $1$.

We can further refine this into polyominoes that *weakly surround* a cell (just covering the four edge-adjacent cells) and those that *strongly surround* a cell (covering all $8$ squares which share a vertex with the hole). Thanks to Julian Rosen for clarifying this distinction.

My original intuition was that this is always possible, but I was having trouble proving it; after enough struggling to show it was true, I started searching for counterexamples. Here is a polyomino with $48$ cells which does not even weakly surround a one-celled region, which is not too difficult to verify by hand:

[image]

After some modifications, I've reduced this down to a simply-connected solution with $26$ cells:

[image]

I have a size-$23$ example of a polyomino which does not strongly surround a hole:

[image]

**What is the smallest polyomino that cannot surround a single-celled hole?** I am interested in this question for both the weak and strong cases.

I've written some code to explore this, and have confirmed that all of the $1,227,708$ free polyominoes on at most $14$ cells can strongly surround a hole. How much can we tighten these bounds?

Comment: For that second one, you're definitely missing more than a single hole. There's no way that polyomino tiles the plane.

Comment: I am *not* asking whether polyominoes tile the plane; I'm asking whether the complement of disjoint copies of them can have connected components of size $1$. [Here](https://i.imgur.com/ktaunEB.png) is an image of a polyomino surrounding a $1\times 1$ hole, for reference.

Comment: @RiversMcForge: I think you may be interpreting the question as asking about polyominoes which tile the whole plane except for one square? I'm asking about a much weaker condition, as evidenced by the computational data mentioned in the post; the former property implies tiling the whole plane, as sketched out in a comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3958842/how-good-can-a-near-miss-polyomino-packing-be). Let me know if there's a way I can make the wording of this post clearer!

Comment: Is it correct that to surround a square, we should cover the 8 adjacent squares (including the diagonally adjacent ones)?

Comment: @JulianRosen: I was thinking just about the $4$ edge-adjacent squares, but that's also an interesting question! For all $8$ adjacent, I’ve checked that every polyomio on up to $13$ cells works; of course the $26$-cell counterexample given in the OP is an upper bound for this question, too. I’ll edit in this variant to the OP.

Comment: Am I missing something, or is this quite susceptible to computer analysis?  It seems like, for a fixed $N$-polyomino, you can determine whether it can weakly surround a single-celled hole for certain in $O(N^5)$, and in practice very much faster.  When you checked up to $13$ cells, presumably you used a computer program to do it?  Was it not fast enough to extend the check further, or did you just not have the full list of free polyominoes for larger $N$?

Comment: @mjqxxxx: Yes, my program's bottleneck was generating all $14$-ominoes more than having to check them. If you know of nicely computer-parseable lists of polyominoes, that would be great! In the meantime, I think giving it a longer runtime might let me extend the $13$-cell results a bit further (perhaps even finding a counterexample!) before it becomes intractable.

Comment: This is just a idle thought, but what about looking at the problem in reverse; i.e., given a unit square hole (either weakly or strongly surrounded), establish some kind of constraint on how its neighbors may be connected, which in turn limits the features of a polyomino that cannot leave such a hole.  Perhaps this is too nebulous or difficult but it was just something that seemed to offer a different perspective than generating polyominoes and then seeing if they can be arranged to leave such a hole.

Comment: Do rotated copies of $P$ count as copies?

Comment: @GoodBoy: Yes, any rotation or flip of $P$ counts. If only translation were allowed, the $V$-pentomino would not strongly surround a hole, and neither of [these two](https://imgur.com/a/AS1bDp3) octominoes would weakly surround a hole.

Comment: Your size-$23$ upper bound is nicely symmetric.  It would be easier to verify (if true) that there are no smaller examples with that symmetry.

Comment: In your $23$-cell example, can't you hollow it out to reduce cell count?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri: Yes, but then it would not be a polyomino, because it would not be edge-connected. (One can get down to $12$ cells by relaxing connectivity - take the borders of $5\times 5$ square except for the four corners.)

Comment: But can't you remove the 7 interior cells and just add 3 at the corners of the resulting 5x3 empty rectangle, enough to connect the outer edges to each other?  That gets you down to 19, right?

Comment: @mjqxxxx:  That can strongly surround a hole as shown in [this image](https://i.imgur.com/UliT7Q9.png).

Comment: Do you have a lower bound? For example, have you brute-forced up to $n = 10$ or anything?

Comment: @PeterKagey: Yes - see the last paragraph of the original post. I've checked all polyominoes up to $14$ cells; $15$ might be in reach, though it would take a while to run.

Comment: I just wanted to comment on what a nicely formulated problem this is (can't +1 more than once!)  It's simply stated but the answer is non-trivial.  Also, in a sense this is the *hardest* problem of this type.  A natural generalization is to look for minimal polyominoes that cannot (strongly) surround a hole of shape $P$, for some polyomino $P$.  For all $P$ with size > $1$ that I've checked, the minimal polyominoes have size $\le 11$, making them easy enough to find through exhaustive search.

Comment: @mjqxxxx: I think I can actually prove that every polyomino of size at least $2$ fails to be strongly surrounded by at least one of [these](https://i.imgur.com/w4ow6HD.png) three polyominoes - there is a finite list of configurations of the form "this cell must be filled, this one must be unfilled, etc", at least one of which must appear in every polyomino's strongly-surrounding configuration, and none of which are satisfied by all three of these polyominoes.

Answer (score 9):

This is by no means a complete answer, but as I mentioned in my last comment, we can make some headway by restricting a computer search to particular symmetry classes.  I've been able to check all the free polyominoes of size $N \le 23$ that have a horizontal or vertical symmetry axis (a class that contains OP's size-$23$ non-strongly-surrounding example).  Within this symmetry class, there are no non-weakly-surrounding examples of size $N \le 23$, and the smallest non-strongly-surrounding examples have size $N=23$; so OP's example is minimal.  Of the $464188$ size-$23$ free polyominoes with a horizontal or vertical axis of symmetry, there are just *two* that cannot strongly surround a single cell: the example given in the question, and the polyomino pictured below.

[image: non-strongly-surrounding symmetric polyomino]

Heuristically, one might expect minimal examples to have some symmetry, because symmetric polyominoes have the fewest "different-looking local regions", and hence the fewest different possibilities for packing local regions around a hole.  Next steps, then, might be to check the other two large symmetry classes for free polyominoes: $180^\circ$ rotational symmetry around a point, and reflection symmetry across a diagonal.

---

*Update:*
Checking the polyominoes with rotational symmetry around a point turned up the following minimal (within that class) non-strongly-surrounding example, with size $20$:

[image: non-strongly-surrounding rotationally symmetric polyomino]

---

*Second update:*
Checking the polyominoes with a diagonal reflection symmetry, there are exactly two minimal (within that class) non-strongly-surrounding examples with size $19$.  One is formed by removing an interior cell from the previous example (as already pointed out in a comment), and the other is new:

[image] [image]

---

*Third update:*
In order to make progress on the non-weakly-surrounding case (which is a more stringent criterion, so the minimal examples are at least as large), I looked at polyominoes with both vertical and horizontal reflection symmetries.  The size-$25$ example below provides an improved upper bound for this case.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this investigation! I notice that both your example and the one in the OP have the line of reflection passing through a cell; did you also check cases where the line coincides with edges between cells? (Obviously this doesn't have $N=23$ examples, since the number of cells must be even, but perhaps it does for lower even $N$.)

Comment: @RavenclawPrefect: Yes, the reflection-symmetric cases do include both types of line; I checked polyominoes of both even and odd width.

Comment: You can remove one of the central squares in your last picture to get a size-19 example. It loses its rotational symmetry, of course, but it's still symmetric about one of its diagonals.

Comment: Would [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWQdX.png) size-16 version not work, then? It also has 180 degree rotational symmetry, but I'm struggling to see how it fails.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: It can strongly surround a hole as shown [here](https://i.imgur.com/CHklcyn.png).

Comment: I went through polyominoes that are centrally symmetric about a central cell, rather than a vertex; the three minimal examples are all of size 23, pictured [here](https://imgur.com/a/aseVK5B).